# querying a yaml parameter using sed is not returning the first occurrence

Tags: regex, bash, sed, yaml

I am trying to get a parameter from a yaml file using `sed`

The files looks like:

```
service:
  vhost: host1
  port: 8080

database:
  vhost: host2
  port: 8080
```

and I need the value from `service.vhost`

for doing that I am using

```
echo $value | sed -e 's/.*service.*vhost:\s\?\(\S*\).*/\1/';
```

but instead of `host1` I am getting `host2`

What is the reason for this behavior?

I need the first occurrence of the matching expression, the file may come with unknown information and the word "vhost" may appear multiple times

Comment: sed does not match across lines. It can be made to, but it's more trouble than it's worth. YAML is a [very complicated](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format and parsing it reliably isn't something you can do with sed. Why not use any of the many programming languages that have a built-in YAML library, e.g. `echo "$value" | ruby -ryaml -e 'puts YAML.load(ARGF)["service"]["vhost"]'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment above, you're much better off using one of the many programming languages with built-in YAML support, like Ruby:

```sh
$ echo "$value" | ruby -ryaml -e 'puts YAML.load(ARGF)["service"]["vhost"]'
# => host1
```

If you're committed to using sed, though, something like this might work *most* of the time:

```sh
echo "$value" | sed -nE '
  /^service:$/,$ !b
  s/^\s+vhost: (\S+)/\1/
  T
  p; q
'
```

You'll notice that this uses `-E` to use extended regexes and avoid all of those backslashes, and `-n` to suppress automatic printing, since we really just want to print one thing.

Breaking it down by line:

1. `/^service:$/,$` is an address range that matches a line containing `service:` and every subsequent line until the end of the file (`$`). `!` inverts the match (i.e. causes the subsequent command to be executed for lines *not* within the range). `b` unconditionally branches to the end of the cycle. In other words, don't do anything until we get to `service:`.
2. `s/^\s+vhost: (\S+)/\1/` should look familiar. It replaces a line like   `vhost: foo` with `foo`.
3. `T` is like `b` but branches to the end of the cycle only if no successful substitution has been made in this cycle (it's the inverse of `t`). That is, if we didn't match `vhost:` above, don't do anything else on this line.
4. `p` prints the pattern space (which now contains the result of the above substitution). We need this because we used the `-n` switch. `q` quits without further processing. Since we found our match, we're done.

This can, of course, be made a one-liner:

```sh
echo "$value" | sed -nE '/^service:$/,$!b; s/^\s+vhost: (\S+)/\1/; T; p; q'
```

You can [see it in action on TiO](https://tio.run/##K05N@f9fP644tagsMznVSkVfR0VBMYmrWD8upli7LCO/uMRKQSMmWFtTP8ZQnyuEq8BaofD/f5hyLgUFqBoQaQjkFuQXAXkWBhYGXFwpiSWJSYnF6MqMUJT9yy8oyczPK/6vm@cKAA).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the commandline tool [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) written in go:

```
% yq read file.yaml service.vhost
host1
```